# How to save an xslm file as xslx in Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

All:

I am pretty new to Excel and APche POI, I wonder how to read in Excel .xlsm file(Macro Enable excel) and save it as .xlsx file using Apache POI?

Any example will be appreciated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295834/poi-saving-an-excel-file-as-xlsx-after-opening-it-from-xlsm?rq=1

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for help. After reading that code, it seems the code modifies that XSSFWorkbook object, I want to do is saveAs, I still want to continue work on that xlsm workbook object, I wonder how can I reverse those modifies after I save as xlsx( or anyother way to keep it as xlsm file )

Comment: After the code in my linked answer ran there are two files, `Workbook.xlsm` unchanged and `Workbook.xlsx` without the VBA part and changed. So I do not understand your requirement. If you do not wants changings simply do not programming the changings.

Comment: @AxelRichter I guess I did not quite understand how that XSSFWorkbook  works. I thought after calling `opcpackage.removePart(vbapart);` and `wbpart.removeRelationship(relship.getId());` and `workbook.setWorkbookType(XSSFWorkbookType.XLSX);`, the workbook object has already been changed. I wonder if that workbook is still exactly same as the one created from "Workbook.xlsm" at the very beginning? My use case is: I have a xlsm file as template, I process some data in it and saveas xlsx then close that  xlsm file without change it

Comment: How about simply testing my code? It is complete. So no need guessing.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, I did. The data seems ok(no change) in the original xlsm file, since I am pretty new to excel VBA and Apache POI, I just not sure what else parts of that workbook object(not the physical xlsm file) will be changed after calling that `removePart` and `removeRelationship`. Because after save it as xlsx, I still need to continue working on that xlsm workbook object

Comment: Not clear to me what your problem is. The code of course does changing the XSSFWorkbook created from the `Workbook.xlsm` file because it then needs to be written as `Workbook.xlsx`. But surely you can creating a new XSSFWorkbook from the unchanged `Workbook.xlsm` file as often as you wants.

Comment: @AxelRichter Is there a way I can revert those changes, will using `opcpackage.createPart` and `wbpart.addRelationship` and `workbook.setWorkbookType(XSSFWorkbookType.XLSM);` do that?

Comment: Why? You can creating a new XSSFWorkbook from the unchanged Workbook.xlsm file as often as you wants.

Comment: @AxelRichter I want to keep those data value changes and VBA code currently made to that workbook object( before turning it into XLSX type) and working on some other jobs with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making an answer from my comments. Hope it will be more clear then.

The following code does creating a `XSSFWorkbook` from a `Workbook.xlsm` template which remains unchanged.

It does changings in this workbook then and, before saving a copy as `*.xlsx`, the current state will be saved as `WorkbookNew.xlsm` file. So the macros stays preserved.

Then the `VBA` will be removed, the content type will be set to `XLSX` and further changings will be made. Then this copy will be saved as `WorkbookNew.xlsx` file.

After that, the previous workbook state will be got back by creating the workbook again from the previous saved `WorkbookNew.xlsm` file. Then further changings will be made and after all the final state of the  `WorkbookNew.xlsm` file will be written out.

So we have the unchanged `Workbook.xlsm` template, the `WorkbookNew.xlsx` **and** the `WorkbookNew.xlsm` then.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class ReadXSLMWriteXLSXWorkbook {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook workbook;
  Sheet sheet;
  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  FileOutputStream out;

  //create workbook from XLSM template
  workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Workbook.xlsm"));

  //do changings
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  row = sheet.getRow(0);
  if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(0);
  cell = row.getCell(0);
  if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("changed in XLSM before writing as XLSX");

  //write out the current state
  out = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookNew.xlsm");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();

  //save copy as XLSX ----------------START
  //remove VBA
  OPCPackage opcpackage = workbook.getPackage();
  //get and remove the vbaProject.bin part from the package
  PackagePart vbapart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/vbaProject.bin")).get(0);
  opcpackage.removePart(vbapart);
  //get and remove the relationship to the removed vbaProject.bin part from the package
  PackagePart wbpart = workbook.getPackagePart();
  PackageRelationshipCollection wbrelcollection = wbpart.getRelationshipsByType("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/vbaProject");
  for (PackageRelationship relship : wbrelcollection) {
   wbpart.removeRelationship(relship.getId());
  }
  //set content type to XLSX
  workbook.setWorkbookType(XSSFWorkbookType.XLSX);

  //do changings only in XLSX
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  row = sheet.getRow(1);
  if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(1);
  cell = row.getCell(1);
  if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("changed before writing as XLSX");

  //write out the XLSX
  out = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  //save copy as XLSX ----------------END

  //get back the previous saved state
  workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("WorkbookNew.xlsm"));

  //do changings
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  row = sheet.getRow(2);
  if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(1);
  cell = row.getCell(2);
  if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("changed in XLSM after writing as XLSX");

  //write out the XLSM
  out = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookNew.xlsm");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.

Comment: BTW, could you tell what can I use in POI to implement VBA's Sheet.Range(). I can not find according function to select a range and give value to those cells

Comment: @Kuan: Asking a question, getting an answer and then asking further questions in comments is not how this site works. As a member for 5 years you should know this already. This site needs a single concrete question for providing one or more valuable answers to exactly this question. This for each single concrete question.

Comment: Ok, right, I have put my question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240401/how-to-implement-vbas-sheet-range-function-in-apache-poi    Thanks for help.