# Implementing VBA's Sheet.range() function in Apache POI

Tags: vba, excel, apache-poi

All:

I am pretty new to Apache POI, as the title said, I want to find according API of that Range() function, or APIs that can work together to build that function, for example:

In VBA:

```
Application.getSheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:F3")
```

In POI, after I get the sheet, I am not sure what is best way to implement that Range():

```
new WorkBook(/* excel file input stream*/).getSheet("Sheet1") // then what?
```

Comment: There is nothing like `VBA` `Range` in `apache poi` until now. But what to use instead depends on what exactly you needs to do with the range of cells. Have you read [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) especially [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+rows+and+cells) and the followings already?

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks and Yes, I read thru the whole page. That is the last step I want to take, cos I hate to parse the Range Address String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like `VBA` `Range` in `apache poi` until now. But what to use instead depends on what exactly you needs to do with the range of cells. If the need is getting the `Cell`s from a string like "A2:F3". Then [CellRangeAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html) may be of a help.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelCellRange {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("file.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("file.xls"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  System.out.println("This is sheet: " + sheet.getSheetName());

  CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("D1:G8");
  int firstRow = cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow();
  int lastRow = cellRangeAddress.getLastRow();
  int firstColumn = cellRangeAddress.getFirstColumn();
  int lastColumn = cellRangeAddress.getLastColumn();

  for (int r = firstRow; r <= lastRow; r++) {
   for (int c = firstColumn; c <= lastColumn; c++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    if (row == null) {
     System.out.println(new CellAddress(r, c) + " is in totally empty row.");
    } else {
     Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
     String content = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println(new CellAddress(r, c) + " contains " + content);
    }
   }
  }

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Btw.: The whole [Package org.apache.poi.ss.util](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/package-summary.html) is worth attention.

Comment: BTW< one question about `CellRangeAddress.valueOf("D1:G8");` How does POI know which sheet this range address created from?

Comment: @Kuan: `CellRangeAddress` does not know something about a sheet. `CellRangeAddress` is **not** the same as `VBA` `Range`. It is only a utility for mapping strings like `"A1:Z10"'  to row number  / column number of first cell and last cell of the range of cells and vice versa and providing some intersect-testing utilities.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I figured it out later myself, now I know why it is called util class